# Using Helper $time->niceShort with german settings in CakePHP 1.2

Tags: cakephp, localization, time, helper, cakephp-1.2

I want to use the CakePHP Helper "time" and his method niceShort to transform a date into a nice, easy to read one. Instead of the english default transformation I want to use a localized version (in my case: "german") but I don't know where to set this. How can I localize this method?

```
echo $time->niceShort($comment['created']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think cake handles date localization very well you might need to use $time->format() see http://cakeqs.org/eng/questions/view/localizing_time_helper and this ticket http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/638-time-helper-i18n

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully set localization parameters, `niceShort` finds right month/day names.

Regarding to [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp) change these:

```
$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'ger')

Configure::write('Config.language', 'ger');

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.utf8','de_DE','de_DE','deu_deu');
```